# fsockopen will not send post data

Tags: php, arrays, post, fsockopen

SOLVED: Issue was in Content-type. Should have been

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

### Helping link: http://www.bradino.com/php/empty-post-array/

I cannot seem to get `POST` data to send. I've combed over this method for a while now and each time I run a test, the `$_POST` array is empty.

```
    $output = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $params = "method=updateOrder&xml=".$output;
    $response = Rest::Post("example.com", 80, "/resource/path.php", $params);
```

Above is another method I call statically which creates the `HttpRequest` with the desired method. Below is the method that gets sub-called and passed the same data but including the method name. IE: `POST`.

```
private static function httpRequest($host, $port, $method, $path, $params)
            {
                //Check method  
                if(empty($method))
                    $method = "GET";
                $method = strtoupper($method);

                //Port
                if(empty($port))
                    $port = 80;

                //Build Querystring
                $data = "";
                if(!empty($params) && $method == "GET")
                    foreach($params as $name => $value)
                        {
                            $data .= $name . "=" . urlencode($value) . "&";
                        }
                if($method == "GET" && !empty($data))
                    $path .= "?" . $data;


                //connection
                $socket = fsockopen($host, $port);
                if(!$socket)
                    die("Socket failed, no connection.");

                //Write Data and headers to stream
                fputs($socket, $method ." ". $path . " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
                fputs($socket, "Host: " . $host . "\r\n");
                if($method === "POST")
                    {
                        fputs($socket, "Content-type: text/xml\r\n");
                        fputs($socket, "Content-length: " . strlen($params) . "\r\n");
                    }

                fputs($socket, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

                //Write body
                if($method === "POST")
                    fputs($socket, $params);

                //Gets headers
                $responseHeader = "";
                do
                {
                    $responseHeader .= fgets($socket, 1024);
                }
                while(strpos($responseHeader, "\r\n\r\n") === false);

                //Gets body
                $responseBody = "";
                while(!feof($socket))
                    $responseBody .= fgets($socket, 1024);

                //Done & return
                fclose($socket);
                return array(0=>$responseHeader, 1=>$responseBody);
            }
```

Comment: Do you get an error message or anything? Also are you aware of curl or the http extension, or PEARs HTTP_Request2 class? (If you really must write your own HTTP handler, declare it /1.0 if you do not deal with the additional caching/transfer-encoding features.)

Comment: Any reason you're going down to the fsock layer instead of using file_put_contents+streams or curl? Either of those would accomplish the same thing with far less pain.

Comment: I setup the resource which is called to response back some a success message and dump the contents of post. Below is the response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2011 15:29:16 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9 Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Length: 23 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html 

Got the post!

Array ( )

Comment: Are you trying to send the post data as an array or a string?

Comment: This implementation is for testing purposes. Eventually I will bump to cURL, but it is currently not enabled. Currently I was attempting to pass the data as a string.

Comment: It looks like you need to convert your array into a string similar to what you are doing for GET.

Comment: probably necessary to urlencode your xml, otherwise any `&` chars could create an invalid POST body: `$params = "method=updateOrder&xml=".urlencode((string)$output)`

Comment: Does the `php://input` stream contain anything?

Comment: php://input dumps: method=updateOrder (I eliminated the XML data for now)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the [built-in cURL library](https://www.php.net/curl).

```
function httpRequest($host, $port = 80, $method = 'GET', $path = '/', $params = null)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

  if ( ! empty($port) )
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
  
  if ( ! empty($method) && $method == 'POST' )
  {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host . ( ! empty($path) ? $path : '/' ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

    if ( ! empty($params) )
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
  }
  else
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host . ( ! empty($path) ? $path : '/' ) . ( ! empty($params) ? '?' . $params : null ));

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  
  curl_close($ch);
  
  return explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
}
```

The function above will return an array containing the headers and the body.

Comment: Currently that's not activated. While I will end up using CURL, I'd like to persist with fsockets for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

Change

```
fputs($socket, "Content-type: text/xml\r\n");
```

to

```
fputs($socket, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
```